# Does Vertical Slice Architecture Violate the DRY Principle?

Tags: architecture

I've been learning about Vertical Slice Architecture recently.

I understand that the ideal is for each slice to be independent, but that seems to imply that some information or functionality may be duplicated across slices. For instance, user authentication information might be needed in multiple slices, but fundamentally, it would originate from a specific slice managing authentication (let's say, an "Auth Slice").

In such scenarios, writing code to fetch the authentication information in each slice seems to go against the DRY principle.

How does Vertical Slice Architecture reconcile with the DRY principle?

And how should one approach resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Vertical Slice Architecture does not mean you can't share things between slices (but you do not share "by default") You still can use some shared domains, helper methods, etc.
2. *For instance, user authentication information might be needed in multiple slices*

   Authentication is so called cross-cutting and cross-cutting concerns (auth, logging, monitoring, etc.) usually are another dimension which is handled separately (i.e. the login/logout itself is a feature but the authentication information and authorization is a cross-cutting concern which is shared, if you imagine handling request as pipeline it will be "before" the feature slices)
3. There is a common misconception about DRY principle you should be aware of, code looking the same does not mean that there is a DRY violation happening, DRY is about knowledge duplication, i.e. when you are solving the same problem in different places (possibly even differently, so code can actually differ vastly).

More:

- [What should I consider when the DRY and KISS principles are incompatible?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400183/what-should-i-consider-when-the-dry-and-kiss-principles-are-incompatible)
- [Vertical Slice Architecture: Duplicate logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUiWfhAhgQw&t=2245s&ab_channel=NDCConferences)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand the DRY principle. Let me ask an additional question to further my understanding. For example, suppose we have an application that allows us to see a simple posting, “Authentication slice”, "Posting slice” ,"Common slice" If I want to determine in the Post slice whether it is me or another user who is not me (i.e., to get authentication information), do I create that code in the Common Slice and the Post slice depends on the Common Slice?

Comment: @せいゆう As I wrote in the answer - in the frameworks/patterns I usually work with the authorization would not be a slice at all (authorization functionality  like login/logout will be though). Another way (compared to the pipeline abstraction) to imagine the cross-cutting concerns such as authorization will be  would be an aspect-oriented approach where you have slices and then they are wrapped in aspects, but you can have cross-cutting concerns represented in the slices itself using some shared functionality/library (it is not required to be a slice itself though).

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand a little better, and I'd like to understand more if possible, so can you give me an example of the slice you speak of?

Comment: @せいゆう Personally I tend to use feature slices for business/"client facing" features, like for example in case of web shop such features could be authentication (login/logout), products (view), order (add item, remove item, complete order), etc. Cross-cutting concerns usually represent either non-functional requirements (logging, metrics) or commonly shared ones like security/authorization (see for example [Microservices and Cross-Cutting Concerns](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/microservices-cross-cutting-concerns)) article

Comment: @せいゆう small fix to the first comment _"authorization functionality like login/logout will be though"_ should be _"authentication functionality"_ .

Comment: Okay, maybe I was thinking of slicing from the perspective of the system, not from the perspective of the user. I think that was my mistake. For example, I was thinking of security as a single slice, not as a shared slice.
Thank you for your thoughtful response, it helps me understand a little better.