# Can a layer method call another method on the same layer in an onion architecture?

Tags: c#, architecture, onion-architecture

Don't seem to find a good explanation for this.
Is it a bad practice to have e.g. a method on one layer call another method on the same layer?

Comment: Yes it can, Very common with application services.

Comment: So it is a good practice if I got an order service method with its own dependencies I can call a user service with some different dependencies ? Is there a documentation for this answer ?

Comment: wouldn't make much sense, if model can ever only talk to view-model and vice versa, would it? Of course you can have deep call-stacks within the same "layer".

Comment: You should include the exact scenario you have in the question with real examples. Architecture guidelines work best when these details are known. On a Higher level, As long as you follow SRP and good Encapsulation it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - it depends.

The main concern is to prevent circular dependencies between same level components (which is not an issue when performing cross-layer calls for obvious reasons) i.e. `ServiceA` needs `ServiceB` which needs `ServiceA`. To prevent this I personally either introduce a "sub-layer" for shared functionality (something similar to the enterprise and application services separation in [service oriented architecture](https://github.com/gurustron/stream-notes/blob/main/Misc/Software%20Architecture%20Fundamentals/Beyond%20Basics.md#6-soa-fundamentals)) or move them into some kind of helper methods.

P.S.

1. Sometimes it is ok to duplicate similar code (instead of moving it into some shared component/invoking existing one). The famous [Don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle is quite often should be applied not to similar code but "business knowledge" - i.e. the same functionality/concept should be coded only once.
2. Check out also - [Does Vertical Slice Architecture Violate the DRY Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76766212/2501279)